# Installing therubyracer 0.12.1 gem in Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am wanting therubyracer 0.12.1 on a windows machine.

I have seen the post on SO about installing the precompiled 0.11.1 version - but I dont want that version.

Can somebody please tell me how I can achieve this!?

Answer (score 1):

On windows `gem 'therubyracer'` is not required as it is used to provide the runtime environment and runtime environment already supports on windows. So just comment the `#gem 'therubyracer'`

Comment: But my other coding environments need it...so how do I do a logic in my gem file saying, if windows, dont bother, if anything else - do bother?

Comment: @RenegadeAndy `:platform` option. Look up `bundler`'s docs on that.